# how to use the iterative operator to get the value into textbox in html and php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session

How to use the iterative operator to get the value into textbox in html and PHP

I am having as follows:

```
   <div class="text_right">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus  minlength="4" size="30" value="<?php echo empty($this->session->store['loginData']['username']) ? '' : $this->session->store['loginData']['username']; ?>" readonly />
      <br/><br/>
   </div>
```

But what I need is I have to fill the textbox with a session value `$this->session->store['respondent_info']['name']`, if that session value is empty then I have to fill that textbox with `$this->session->store['loginData']['username'];`  is it possible if so can someone help me please.

Comment: Are you using CI session library? or any other custom library?

Comment: CI session library only

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI Session library,

Then you can get session data as

```
$re_info = $this->session->userdata("respondent_info");
```

then you can use as

```
echo $re_info["name"];
```

For `loginData`

```
$login_info = $this->session->userdata("loginData");
```

For your question:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus  minlength="4" size="30" value="<?php echo empty($loginData['username']) ? '' : $loginData['username']; ?>" readonly />
```

Comment: how to mention it in the code. if $this->session->store['respondent_info']['name'] is not empty i have to fill it textbox with this value, if this session is empty i have to fill textbox with $this->session->store['loginData']['username'];

Answer (score 0):

To set a session variable in CI

```
$this->load->library('session'); //load session library
$this->session->set_userdata('key','value');
```

and to retrieve it is

```
$this->session->userdata('key');
```

for example let take your case and suppose you have `respondent_info` value stored in a variable say `$res`, then we could set the session as follows:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('respondent_info',$res);
```

and one can retrieve the value as below:

```
$resp_info = $this->session->userdata('respondent_info');
```

Similar is the case with the logged in user details.

After you have saved both the respondent_info and logged in user details in appropriate session variables( Say username is stored with key `logged_username`) you could fetch it back and do your operation as below:

```
$resInfo = $this->session->userdata('respondent_info');

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus  minlength="4" size="30" value="<?php echo (!empty($resInfo)) ? $resInfo : $this->session->userdata('logged_username'); ?>" readonly />
```

You can find more info on CI sessions [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)